# Jackson - combine @JsonValue and @JsonSerialize

Tags: java, json, dictionary, jackson, serialization

I am trying a combination of `@JsonValue` and `@JsonSerialize`. Let's start with my current container class:

```
public class Container {
    private final Map<SomeKey, Object> data;

    @JsonValue
    @JsonSerialize(keyUsing = SomeKeySerializer.class)
    public Map<SomeKey, Object> data() {
        return data;
    }
}
```

In this case, the custom serializer `SomeKeySerializer` is not used.

If I change the container as following, the serializer is called:

```
public class Container {
    @JsonSerialize(keyUsing = SomeKeySerializer.class)
    private final Map<SomeKey, Object> data;
}
```

However, this is not what I want, as this introduces another 'data' level in the output JSON.

Is it possible to combine `@JsonValue` and `@JsonSerialize` in some way?

I could  always write another custom serializer for `Container`, which more or less does the same as the functionality behind `@JsonValue`. This would be more or less a hack, in my opinion.

Jackson version: 2.6.2

Comment: How to you put in data in `private final Map<SomeKey, Object> data;`?

Comment: Actually, I was just trying to reproduce this and it seems to me that using @JsonValue isn't calling the serializer, it's just calling SomeKey.toString(). Is that not what you're seeing?

Comment: Exactly, that is my question :).

Comment: Would be worth filing a bug for -- combining annotations is tricky, and handling of `@JsonValue` is very different from regular getters... but ideally this combination should work, regardless. And it actually seems like something that could be made to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This combination seems to do what you want: make a Converter to extract the Map from the Container, and add @JsonValue to SomeKey itself to serialize it:

```
@JsonSerialize(converter = ContainerToMap.class)
public class ContainerWithFieldData {
    private final Map<SomeKey, Object> data;

    public ContainerWithFieldData(Map<SomeKey, Object> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}

public static final class SomeKey {
    public final String key;

    public SomeKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    @JsonValue
    public String toJsonValue() {
        return "key:" + key;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "SomeKey:" + key;
    }
}

public static final class ContainerToMap extends StdConverter<ContainerWithFieldData, Map<SomeKey, Object>> {
    @Override
    public Map<SomeKey, Object> convert(ContainerWithFieldData value) {
        return value.data;
    }
}

@Test
public void serialize_container_with_custom_keys_in_field_map() throws Exception {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    assertThat(
            mapper.writeValueAsString(new ContainerWithFieldData(ImmutableMap.of(new SomeKey("key1"), "value1"))),
            equivalentTo("{ 'key:key1' : 'value1' }"));
}
```

I simply can't get annotating an accessor method of Container to DTRT at all easily, not in combination with @JsonValue. Given that @JsonValue on the container is basically designating a converter anyway (that is implemented by calling the annotated method), this is effectively what you're after, although not as pleasant as it seems it should be. (tried with Jackson 2.6.2)

(Something I learned from this: key serializers aren't like normal serializers, even though they implement JsonSerializer just the same. They need to call writeFieldName on the JsonGenerator, not writeString, for example. On the deserialization side, the distinction between JsonDeserializer and KeyDeserializer is spelled out, but not on the serialization side. You can make a key serializer from SomeKey with @JsonValue, but *not* by annotating SomeKey with @JsonSerialize(using=...), which surprised me).

Comment: Thanks, this makes more sense. I'll report my question to the Jackson issue tracker, as we are working around the limitations of `@JsonValue` in combination with other annotations in my opinion.

Comment: About your edit: indeed! I noticed the same thing. So far, I have no idea why there is no `KeySerializer`, the inverse of `KeyDeserializer`.

Comment: I can help a bit with this mystery -- at the time when adding custom key handlers, it was possible to use `JsonSerializer` for key serializers (may be invoked same way), but same is not true for `JsonDeserializer`. Trying to avoid adding many new classes, only one was added. In retrospect, it would have probably made more sense to add `KeySerializer` as well, just to prevent surprises.

Comment: +1 for the: "You can make a key serializer from SomeKey with @JsonValue, but not by annotating SomeKey with @JsonSerialize(using=...)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using `@JsonSerialize(using = SomeKeySerializer.class)` instead of `keyUsing`?

[Doc for using()](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/annotation/JsonSerialize.html#using()) says:

> Serializer class to use for serializing associated value.

...while for keyUsing you get:

> Serializer class to use for serializing Map keys of annotated property

Tested it out myself and it works...

```
public class Demo {

  public static class Container {

    private final Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();

    @JsonValue
    @JsonSerialize(using = SomeKeySerializer.class)
    public Map<String, String> data() {
      return data;
    }
  }

  public static class SomeKeySerializer extends JsonSerializer<Map> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(Map value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
      jgen.writeStartObject();
      jgen.writeObjectField("aKeyInTheMap", "theValueForThatKey");
      jgen.writeEndObject();
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
    String s = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(new Container());
    System.out.println(s);
  }
}
```

This is the output when I'm NOT using `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonValue`

```
{
  "data" : {
    "aKeyInTheMap" : "theValueForThatKey"
  }
}
```

And this is the output when I'm using `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonValue`

```
{
  "aKeyInTheMap" : "theValueForThatKey"
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This works indeed, but it doesn't feel right. Aren't we simply replacing the default map serializer with our custom serializer?

Comment: I guess so... if there were any room for "metaphysics" in engineering :)

Comment: I've also stumbled upon [JsonAnyGetter doesn't work with JsonSerialize (except with keyUsing)](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/705) and it may apply to your particular problem, it involves however a slightly different approach since it uses `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.Converter` instead of `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer`...

Comment: Thanks, I saw that too. This example does not include the `@JsonValue` though. I'll wait a bit for other solutions and keep on trying meanwhile. Just replacing everything with our own serializer seems overkill.

Comment: I think the scope of `@JsonValue` is very restricted. I added another, similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33056520/jackson-chaining-of-jsonvalue-and-map.

Comment: LOL you need to upgrade fasterxml to > 2.5.0 [+#47: Support `@JsonValue` for (Map) key serialization](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/commit/ead4e32095e885e73d038824a845f228d860aaed)

Comment: I am using version 2.6.2.

Comment: Try it out with 2.5.0 and if indeed it works then it means that they broke it :)

Comment: Good suggestion! I will try that out later today and let you know.