# Jackson - chaining of @JsonValue and Map

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have the following class:

```
public class SomeKey {
    private final String name;

    @JsonValue
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @JsonCreator
    public SomeKey(final String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

I have the following container:

```
public class Container {
    @JsonSerialize
    private final Map<SomeKey, Object> data;
}
```

In this case, the function `SomeKey.getName()` is used to serialize the key of the maps, as expected. However, if I change the Container as following, the function `SomeKey.toString()` is used:

```
public class Container {
    private final Map<SomeKey, Object> data;

    @JsonValue
    public Map<SomeKey, Object> data() {
        return data;
    }
}
```

In other words, the `@JsonValue` on `SomeKey` is ignored. As far as I can tell, there seems to be some problem with chaining `@JsonValue` annotations. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong here?

Jackson version: 2.6.2

Comment: @araqnid I think answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/33056608/4402596 is also an answer for this question.

Comment: Does the same [issue](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/47) apply?

Comment: This is a version without custom key serializers (which shouldn't be necessary anyway), so it does not apply.

Comment: It is possible that you hit a bug that has just been fixed for 2.6.3 (out as of today actually). Both codes should work; and if latter still doesn't work with 2.6.3, please file a bug against `jackson-databind`.